# separating magento adminhtml from front end

Tags: e-commerce

I would like to know if magento adminhtml can be separated with front end on two different web servers. 
I have two linux box setups and I would like install onto magento admin on of of them and front-end onto another. Any suggestions?  Does anyone knows how to do it? 
Thanks guys for your time.